# PSQL query to create table of relationships given purchases and churn tables

Tags: sql, psql

my SQL-fu isn't what it used to be, so I thought I'd ask you wizards this.

The (simplified) tables in question are:

```
Purchases
- customer_id int
- purchase_date timestamp

Churns
- customer_id int
- churn_date timestamp

Customers
- id int
```

What I would like to end up with is a result set that looks like this:

`customer_id | first_purchase_in_relationship | churn_date (if applicable)`

The trick here is that customers can churn and then "reactivate" and make more purchases, so there may be multiple entries for a customer.

Comment: please provide the code you tried to implement. And errors/expectations about it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach this problem. If a customer couldn't churn and then "reactivate" this would be more or less trivial, but that wrinkle has me stumped.